# Gatsby remark images blur technique

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to use the Gatsby-plugin "gatsby-remark-images" to create blurry images on load which eventually renders the proper sized images when load is complete, but I might be doing this erroneously.

My index page has a Hero component, which is passed down the src of the image as such:

```
import Image from "../posts/img/Image.jpg";
```

...

```
<Hero id="indexPage" src={Image} />
```

My index page query fetches the 6 latest blogposts as such:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      limit: 6
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
      filter: { frontmatter: { category: { eq: "blog"} } }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            slug
          }
          excerpt(pruneLength: 100)
          timeToRead
          frontmatter {
            title
            description
            tags
            date
            category
            thumbnail {
              childImageSharp {
                responsiveSizes(quality: 50, cropFocus: CENTER, toFormat: JPG) {
                  src
                  srcSet
                  sizes
                  base64
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Questions:

Do I need to add the Image to the query, in order to use the base64 method? In that case, how do I do that?

If I want to add the blur up technique to the images fetched from the query, what do I have to do? Do I need to add a state-change between loaded and loading, and change between base64 and src accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

`gatsby-remark-image` is only for processing images linked to from *within* markdown files. See its docs https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-images/

For general image handling, see gatsby-image which has special GraphQL fragments & React component which makes it easy to add responsive, lazy images https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/